# jquery mobile page not showing header and footer after adding Google map v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, mobile

I've added a Google map to v3 to jquery mobile page, map is fine but now can't see header and footer. As I'm new to this any help will gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried anything to address the issue?

Comment: Yes, I spent the best part of yesterday reading and trying different things, none of them worked unfortunately. I'm a bit nervous about fiddling with javascript as I don't fully understand it although I can find my way round the easy bits ie adding lat & long and altering zoom level. I followed the Google Map instructions and the map appears on the map page but know can't see header and footer. I tried as suggested the map-canvas div but wherever I put it the problem still remained the same.

Comment: Check console for errors first. After make sure that map on overpals with header and footer. It can be simply because of z-index. Try to set map size hardcoded small. Like 100x100 pixels and tell if you can see header and footer again.

Comment: Have tried what you suggested with size 100px x100px and map shows still top to bottom but slim and on the left. Still no header and footer though. Checked console and no errors. Have to go and do a bit now but will try putting code on here later. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: How do I add code to this?